# Yii file field is empty

Tags: file-upload, yii

I have file field exactly as [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/how-to-upload-a-file-using-a-model/) link said in my project , i put exactly it's code and change every thing looks like it but when i want it's value by this code :

> ```
> $uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName($model,'image');
> ```

image is empty and i get this error :

> Illegal offset type in isset or empty

I saw Yii add two field for file in the form and first one is hidden and empty why ?

And i assume Yii get it as main image and so it is always empty , How could i get file field value.

- The only difference is it use CActiveRecord but i use CFormModel beacuse i dont have database in this project.
- I can access all the fields by $model->fieldname but this field is empty !!

Edited:

I find [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/265/file-uploads-in-cform-form-builder/) tutorial but i cant use it because my form is in the controllers, view file and get a lot of variable from controller and this tutorials form seems clean:

```
 $form = new CForm('application.views.fileUpload.uploadForm', $model);
```

My view:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                            'id'=>'contacts-form',
                            'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
                            'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
                        )); ?>

                            <div class="fieldtext">
                                <div class="labelbox">
                                    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, Yii::t($this->language,'dialogboxname').":"); ?>
                                </div>
                                <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name',array('value'=>'aaa','size'=>10,'maxlength'=>50,'class'=>'inputbox')); ?>
                            </div>

                            <div class="fieldtext">
                                <div class="labelbox">
                                    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,Yii::t($this->language,'dialogboxemail').":"); ?>
                                </div>
                                <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email',array('value'=>'aaa@aa.com','size'=>17,'maxlength'=>50,'class'=>'inputbox')); ?>
                            </div>

                            <div class="fieldtext subjectbox">
                                <div class="labelbox">
                                    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,Yii::t($this->language,'dialogboxsubject').":"); ?>
                                </div>
                                <?php echo $form->textField($model,'subject',array('value'=>'aaa','size'=>36,'maxlength'=>50,'class'=>'inputbox')); ?>
                            </div>

                            <div class="fieldtext bodybox">
                                <div class="labelbox">
                                    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,Yii::t($this->language,'dialogboxbody').":"); ?>
                                </div>
                                <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'body',array('value'=>'aaa','rows'=>6, 'cols'=>35,'class'=>'inputbox')); ?>
                            </div>

                            <div class="fieldtext bodybox">

                                    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'image'); ?>

                                    <?php echo $form->fileField($model, 'image'); ?>
                            </div>

                            <?php if(CCaptcha::checkRequirements()): ?>
                            <div class="captchabox fieldtext">

                                <div>
                                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,Yii::t($this->language,'dialogboxconfirmcode').":"); ?>
                                <?php $this->widget('CCaptcha',array(
                                        'showRefreshButton' => false,
                                        'clickableImage' => true,

                                    )); ?>
                                        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'verifyCode',array('size'=>5,'maxlength'=>5)); ?>

                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <div class="contactbuttom">
                                <div class="submitcontactform buttomsize">
                                    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton(Yii::t($this->language,'dialogboxsendbuttomn')); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

My Model:

```
<?php
class ContactForm extends CFormModel {
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $subject;
    public $body;
    public $image;
    public $verifyCode;

    /**
     * Declares the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            // name, email, subject and body are required
            array('name, email, subject, body', 'required',
                    ),
            // email has to be a valid email address
            array('email', 'email'),

            array('image', 'file'),
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'verifyCode'=>'Verification Code',
        );
    }

}
```

My Controller:

```
...
$this->model= new ContactForm;
$model = $this->model;

    if(isset($_POST['ContactForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['ContactForm'];

        if($model->validate())
        {
            $name = $model->name;
            $email = $model->email;
            $subject = $model->subject;
            $body = $model->body;

            $uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName($model,'image');

....
```

Funny thing is it check the rule but said it is empty.

Comment: Please share your view code?

Comment: I add some other field in my view like name and email, everything is like that tutorial.

Comment: Share all of your code and we can help.

Comment: I update my question with codes.

Answer (score 1):

The following line is wrong :

```
$uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName($model,'image');
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUploadedFile#getInstanceByName-detail

You should try :

```
$uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('ContactForm[image]');
```

Or:

```
$uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
$uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName($model,'image');
```

has to be replaced with this:

```
$uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
```

`CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName` takes one paramerter, not two https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/web/CUploadedFile.php#L81

It requires name of file-input. So, call it like this:

```
CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('ContactForm[image]'); //if 'ContactForm[image]' is input name
```

Actually, `CUploadedFile::getInstance` calles it as well. But it also resolves input name itself https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/web/CUploadedFile.php#L57

So, I believe, `CUploadedFile::getInstance` is better approach.

**PS:** Not sure why you use `CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName` even though tutorial you refered to uses `CUploadedFile::getInstance` in controller.

Be attentive :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer:

```
     public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Answer();
        var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post());`enter code here`
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            $model->answer_by= \Yii::$app->user->getId();
            $name = $model->answer_attachment;
            var_dump($name);
            $model->answer_attachment = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('btn.jpg');
            var_dump($model->answer_attachment);
             $time=time();
            if(!empty($model->answer_attachment)){
                $model->answer_attachment->saveAs('images/answer/'.$time.'.'.$model->answer_attachment->extension);
                $model->answer_attachment='images/answer/'.$time.'.'.$model->answer_attachment->extension;
            }
            $model->answer_timestamp=$time;
            //$model->save();
            //return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->answer_id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```